# servlet initialization failure in websphere 6.0

Tags: servlets, websphere

I have many servlets in a web applicaton; for some stange reason, only and only one of them always fails in initialization with the following error trace:-

00000045 ServletWrappe E   SRVE0100E: Did not realize  init() exception thrown by servlet MyServletX: java.lang.NullPointerException
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebAppPmiListener.onServletStartInit(WebAppPmiListener.java:120)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.FireOnServletStartInit.fireEvent(WebAppEventSource.java:237)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.util.EventListeners.fireEvent(EventListeners.java:48)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppEventSource.onServletStartInit(WebAppEventSource.java:105)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:261)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:444)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:2841)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:220)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHost.handleRequest(VirtualHost.java:204)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1681)
      at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:77)
      at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:421)
      at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:367)
      at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:94)
      at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:548)
      at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:601)
      at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:934)
      at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1021)
      at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1332)

I could not figure out if there is anything extra ordinary with this servlet. There is no init() method in this servlet and it extends HTTPServlet. Any idea what could be reason? I am using websphere server 6.0.x. How to get more debugging information in this case?

---

Well I don't know still cause of above error, but this is how it started working strangely:- i) Re-applied recommended fixes by IBM for my WAS version (especially there are IBM JDK upgrade related fix patches) ii) created a new profile of server iii) Install web application to new profile and it started working.

Comment: This looks like a product issue.  I would recommend opening a PMR (or upgrading to a supported WAS version).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a product issue.

To debug this problem what i would suggest is to place a simple servlet (kind of Hello World) and deploy it to the server and see what happens.

initialization does not necessarily mean init() method alone.

If you have a static block in your servlet, if you have any variables that are initialized they would all be part of the initialization activity.

Look at the FFDC logs that were generated when this error occurred and that should provide you with clues.

As bkail mentioned, also ensure that yo have the latest fixpacks just to eliminate known problems with the product.

if the hello world servlet works, suggest you place hte servlet code here along with the SystemOut and System Err logs that correspond to this issue along with the relevant FFDC logs and i am sure most of us will be able to help you out with this

HTH

Manglu

Comment: Here is what I checked so far and but no success in resolving issue:-i) There is no static or class level variable in this servlet.     ii) Nothing special in FFDC logs when this error occurred. iii) I also have downloaded and deployed latest recommended fixes for WAS6.1. iv) there are already lot of servlets in my application which gets initialized properly. v) I check on web for WAS 5.1 , in its recommended fix, there is PQ99326 defect which seems to be similar. Check this link:- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27006879

Comment: Does the hello world kind of a servlet work. How about the samples from WebSphere - do they work? I can't believe that this is a product bug.

Comment: I had a look a the defect whch  you mentioned and that seems to affect JSPs. You are doing the right thing by looking at the product support pages to see if this is an existing defect. I honestly do not believe that this is a product bug and i would love to see what happens to the sample applications or the hello world servlets to rule out a product issue.

Comment: IMHO, any time a published library throws NPE, that is a defect in said published library, even if it only happens in response to a defect in the code using it.